# ldap_connect not working with connection string unless port is specifed as second argument

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to understand why `ldab_connect` works only when it's given the port number as second argument :

```
>>> $con = ldap_connect('ldap://ldaphost', 636);
=> ldap link resource #832
>>> ldap_bind($con, 'username', 'password');
=> true
>>>
```

While when it's given in connection string, it does not work:

```
>>> $con = ldap_connect('ldap://ldaphost:636');
=> ldap link resource #833
>>> ldap_bind($con, 'username', 'password');
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in ...eval()'d code on line 1
=> false
```

I am using a laravel package to handle ldap connection and it's very ugly to do the modification inside the vendor folder as the call to ldap_bind is in there.

My php and ldap versions :

```
>>> phpversion()
=> "7.2.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1"
>>> phpversion('ldap')
=> "7.2.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1"
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the second argument is ignored when you provide an LDAP-URL as first parameter.

As you are using `ldap` as scheme (which uses port 389) the port argument you are using is ignored so ldap_bind connects to port 389.

When you add the port 636 (which is used for `ldaps`) to the LDAP-URL the extension tries to use the unencrypted LDAP protocol to connect to the SSL-encrypted port 636. Which doesn't work.

So either use 389 as the port in your LDAP-URL or use `ldaps` as the schema when connecting to port 636

If you are using LDAPv3 you can use the LDAP-URL `ldap://server:389` for ldap_connect and then call `ldap_start_tls` to start a tls encrypted tunnel to your LDAP server...

See the docs at php.net/ldap for more details...

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried using ldaps://hostname:636 but it gives me 'cant contact server' error

Comment: If the server does not implement ldaps then that might be correct. Did you get that port from your LDAP-Admin?

Comment: well not personally but , I got a legacy code that's using those credentials to log users in with LDAP.

Comment: What exactly did you inherit? What was the code that you got (and that worked)?